# Visitors counter based on MySQL database works on half

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I want to make a visitors counter on my websites, so I experiment with MySQL database and counting visitors based on IP address and on dates of their access (each day counts the same IP address as a new visitor). Counter has today part (counts only the current day visitors) and part with counting visitors from websites launch (or launch of counter, to be exact). However, only the today part works.

Get visitors data from database (IP addresses and dates and times of access):

```
// Get data from database
$query_get_data = "select ip_address, access_date_time from $table_name;";

$mysql_conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', $db_name);
if(!$mysql_conn) {
    die("<strong>ERROR WHILE ACCESSING DATABASE `$db_name`!!!</strong>");
    // access the database was unsuccessful
}

$query = mysqli_query($mysql_conn, $query_get_data);
if(!$query) {
    die("<strong>ERROR WHILE FETCHING DATA FROM TABLE `$table_name` IN DATABASE `$db_name`!!!</strong>");
}
```

Count the visitors from acquired data:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        if(isset($visitors_start_count[$row['ip_address'] . ' IN DATE ' . trim(explode(",", $row['access_date_time'])[0])])) {
            ++$visitors_start_count[$row['ip_address'] . ' IN DATE ' . trim(explode(",", $row['access_date_time'])[0])];
        } else {
            $visitors_start_count[$row['ip_address'] . ' IN DATE ' . trim(explode(",", $row['access_date_time'])[0])] = 1;
        }

        if(trim(explode(",", $row['access_date_time'])[0]) == trim(explode(",", $date_time)[0])) {
            if(isset($visitors_today_count[$row['ip_address']])) {
                ++$visitors_today_count[$row['ip_address']];
            } else {
                $visitors_today_count[$row['ip_address']] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Count the total number of visitors:

```
$visitors_num_start = 0;
$visitors_num_today = 0;

foreach($visitor_start_count as $counter) {
    ++$visitors_num_start;
}

foreach($visitors_today_count as $counter) {
    ++$visitors_num_today;
}
```

This is the output that I have:

```
Today is Fri Oct 6th 2017.

You are the 1st visitor today here and 0th from websites launch.
```

I can't find the issue preventing the total part to work. Please, help :(

Comment: For this kind of stuff you can use Google Analytics (or any other analytics), it's much easier to implement (basically you copy-paste a snippet) and won't kill your server.

To answer your question: I think you overcomplicate things, create a simple query with group by date and having todays date and you got the number of visitors for today

Comment: Let your database do the work - select count(*) from (select distinct IP_ADDRESS from $table_name where date > $yesterday). This code will take ages to run az soon as you have any meaningful number of visiitors.

Comment: Well, it's just experiment, I never said it's going to be actually implemented in my websites, only I want to add visitors count to my websites and finding way to do so. Thank you @SzántóZoltán for your Google Analytics advice, will take a look meanwhile :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an s! You are filling the data into `$visitors_start_count` but then use `$visitor_start_count` (visitor**s**_start_count) when counting.

In general, though, I'd advise to let your database do the heavy lifting and use a SELECT that uses a condition to find the right rows (today, last week, since the beginning of time) and GROUP BY date and IP address.

Comment: Yes, that was the thing :D Damn forgotten `s` :D Thank you :)